# Flutter Android 11 errno 1

Tags: android, flutter

im downloading a pdf file in this address  :

```dart
/storage/emulated/0/documents/download folder/2021-08-30-16:37:55.544095iH46x.pdf
```

it works fine in android 10 and below.
but on android 11 i get this error :

```dart
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/documents/download folder/2021-08-30-16:37:55.544095iH46x.pdf' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)
```

these are my permissions on manifest :

```dart
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

these are my permissions on permission handler :

```dart
      Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> result = await [
        Permission.storage,
        Permission.manageExternalStorage,
        Permission.mediaLibrary].request();
```

full code :

```dart
 String fullPath;
    try {

      Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> result = await [
        Permission.storage,
        Permission.manageExternalStorage,
        Permission.mediaLibrary].request();


      if (result[Permission.storage].isGranted && result[Permission.manageExternalStorage].isGranted && result[Permission.mediaLibrary].isGranted  ) {
        // a custom method for getting path 
        String dir = await Utility.makeAndGetDownloadFolder();
        
        // preparing access token
        final storage = Storage.FlutterSecureStorage();
        String accessToken = await storage.read(key: "accessToken");
         
        // generating random string for the pdf file name
        String dateNow = DateTime.now().toString();
        dateNow = dateNow.replaceAll(' ', '');
        String randomName = dateNow + Utility.getRandomString(5);
        fullPath = "$dir/$randomName.pdf";

        // preparing dio request
        String url;
        Dio dio = Dio();
        Response response;


          url = "https://www.example.com/api/downloadFile";
          FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
            "idAdvertise": idAdvertise,
          });
          response = await dio.post(url,
              data: formData,
              options: Options(
                  headers: {
                    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $accessToken',
                  },
                  responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
                  followRedirects: false,
                  validateStatus: (status) {
                    return status < 500;
                  }), onReceiveProgress: (int received, int total) {
                if (total != -1) {
                  setState(() {
                    _progress = received / total * 100;
                  });
                }
              });
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            File file = File(fullPath);
            // code reach untill here and then it jumps in catch 
            var raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
            raf.writeFromSync(response.data);
            await raf.close();
            // show notification on success
            await showNotification(fullPath);
          }else if(response.statusCode == 404){
           // status code 404 do something 
            print("status 404");
          }else{
            print("status code download is ${response.statusCode}");
   Components.customSnackBar(context,AppStr.errDownloadFailed403);
          }
          setState(() {

          });
      } 
    } catch (e) {
      print("catch is $e");
    }
```

please dont suggest me using path_provider cause its not what i need

Comment: good news is I won't recommend path_provider, bad news is I don't have a package to recommend, the problem is Android 11 changed the way to save files now using SAF and other new utilities for security reasons, so if you now Java you could implement your own method channel to send the data and save the file in download or try with packages that try to solve this, but I'm not sure which is the best one, this is one https://pub.dev/packages/flowder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who still wonders how i fixed the issue,
i used path provider to save the file in the cache and then after saving the file then i moved the file to downloads folder with the [flutter_file_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_dialog) package

source code :

```dart
        //getting the cache directory from path_provider
        Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

        final storage = Storage.FlutterSecureStorage();
        String accessToken = await storage.read(key: "accessToken");


        var fileName = Utility.generateRandomFileName();
        fullPath = "${dir.path}/$fileName.pdf";
        bool checkFileExist = true;

        while (checkFileExist) {// if file already exists with this name then we generate different name
          if (await File(fullPath).exists()) {
            fileName = Utility.generateRandomFileName();
            fullPath = "${dir.path}/$fileName.pdf";
          } else {
            checkFileExist = false;
          }
        }

        Dio dio = Dio();
        Response response;
        FormData formData;

          formData = FormData.fromMap({
            "id": widget.id,
          });

        response = await dio.post('https://example.com/downloadfile',
              data: formData,
              options: Options(
                  headers: {
                    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $accessToken',
                  },
                  responseType: ResponseType.bytes,
                  followRedirects: false,
                  validateStatus: (status) {
                    return status < 500;
                  }),
              onReceiveProgress: (int received, int total) {
                if (total != -1) {
                  setState(() {
                    _progressDownloading = received / total * 100;
                  });
                }
              });

          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
              File file = File(fullPath);
              var raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.write);
              raf.writeFromSync(response.data);
              await raf.close();

              // moving the file from cache to anywhere you want
              final params = SaveFileDialogParams(sourceFilePath: fullPath);
              await FlutterFileDialog.saveFile(params: params).then((value) async {
                if(value != null){//if the file saved successfully
                  await showNotification();
                }else{
                 print('error couldnt move the pdf file');
                }
              });

              file.delete();//deleting the pdf from cache 
             }else{
               print('something went wrong');
             }
```